# How to Modify Default Address Field in Professional Edition

Tags: address

Using Salesforce Professional Edition and was wondering Is it possible to modify the default Address field in our Leads? When I go to App Setup > Customize > Leads > Fields, there is no Edit link next to the Address field. (see attached screenshots).

We want to pass the following values based on Country:

US
 - State & Postal Code

CANADA
 - Province & Postal Code

ALL OTHER COUNTRIES
 - Postal Code

The default address field in Salesforce does not show much information, just Country & State. If the lead is from Canada, it just shows CA & no Province. And, Postal Code is never shown.

Basically, we want to modify the default Address field to capture more information.

Answer (score 1):

Address field is a [Compound Field](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/compound_fields_address.htm) on Lead Object.

You can not modify this Address field from UI or API.

> Standard address compound fields are read-only, and are only accessible using the SOAP and REST APIs.
>
> In Developer, Professional, Enterprise, Unlimited, and Performance editions, Salesforce can automatically add or update geolocation fields for Account, Contact, Lead, and WorkOrder records.

If you want to load data to Address field you can migrate the data into the respective fields of this Address.

> - Accuracy
> - City
> - Country
> - CountryCode
> - Latitude
> - Longitude
> - PostalCode
> - State
> - StateCode
> - Street

Or, You can use API to insert or update data into those fields.

Query the record as follows:

```
SELECT City, 
Country,
CountryCode, 
Latitude , 
Longitude, 
PostalCode, 
State, 
StateCode, 
Street 
From Lead 
WHERE Id = <Lead Id>
```

And put them into this list and do your desired update.

Comment: Unless they pay extra, PE edition doesn't have API access.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, this is what I can suggest.

Since the standard Address field is not editable, one work around for this issue is to hide the standard "Address field" using Page Layouts and create "Custom fields" depending on the information you need to capture and place them on the Lead object.

For example: If you want to have individial fields to capture "State","Country" "Zip code" create individual fields with their names and make it visible on the Lead page using Page Layouts.

Posting screen shots of your issue would help a lot.